# Algorithm to find best dimensions combination

Tags: algorithm, multidimensional-array, dimensions

I am looking for an algorithm to find the best dimension combination to accomplish a desired result.

Take the following as example:

```
|   A    |    B   |   C   |  y  |
|--------|--------|-------|-----|
| dog    | house1 | green | 30  |
| dog    | house1 | blue  | 15  |
| cat    | house1 | green | 20  |
| cat    | house2 | red   |  5  |
| turtle | house3 | green | 50  |
```

A, B, C are the measured dimensions.
y is the measured result.

If I want to get all combinations of dimensions that accomplish y >= 50 so the results will be:

```
turtle, house3, green
turtle, any,    green
turtle, house3, any
turtle, any,    any
any,    house3, green
any,    house3, any
any,    any,    green
any,    house1, green
any,    house1, any
```

Maybe it's a easy problem but I was trying to figure an optimal solution in terms of O(n) and I didn't found it.

Comment: Almost certainly related to [Linear Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming). The solutions will be parts of (maybe "slices through"?) the simplex. Looking forward to see approaches for this. BTW: **linear** referring to the number of rows of the table? This may be difficult. My gut feeling is that it will be at least O(n*m), for 'n' rows and 'm' columns, and is likely to be even more expensive...

Comment: Can you explain the outputs?  In what sense is `any, house1, any` a solution?  Do you add the corresponding `y` values, getting `30 + 15 + 20 = 65` in that case?  (Perhaps more background would be useful: what sort of quantity does `y` represent, and why does it make sense to be summing elements of the `y` column?)

Comment: @MarkDickinson you are right, sum(y) when A=any, B=house1, C=any

Comment: do you know the values of turtle, house1,2... - is this a sum of those values? Or all you've got is this example table it is your task to guess other combinations using this table only? If you know the basic values this seems like solvable by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm

Comment: @dfens I don't know all possible values of each column but I can get them using some operations like `distinct(A)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Back here, 8 years later to answer the question using ClickHouse:

```sql
WITH table AS (
    SELECT 'dog' AS a, 'house1' AS b, 'green' AS c, 30 AS y
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'dog' AS a, 'house1' AS b, 'blue' AS c, 15 AS y
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'cat' AS a, 'house1' AS b, 'green' AS c, 20 AS y
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'cat' AS a, 'house2' AS b, 'red' AS c,  5 AS y
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'turtle' AS a, 'house3' AS b, 'green' AS c, 50 AS y
)
SELECT a, b, c, sum(y) y FROM table GROUP BY CUBE(a, b, c)
HAVING y >= 50
FORMAT PrettyCompactMonoBlock;

┌─a──────┬─b──────┬─c─────┬───y─┐
│ turtle │ house3 │ green │  50 │
│ turtle │ house3 │       │  50 │
│ turtle │        │ green │  50 │
│ turtle │        │       │  50 │
│        │ house3 │ green │  50 │
│        │ house1 │ green │  50 │
│        │ house3 │       │  50 │
│        │ house1 │       │  65 │
│        │        │ green │ 100 │
│        │        │       │ 120 │
└────────┴────────┴───────┴─────┘
```

Answer (score 4):

Start with a work queue containing `(any, any, ..., any), 0`. The elements of this queue will be pairs consisting of a combination and a number of elements on the left that cannot be changed from `any` (this will make more sense shortly). Until the work queue is empty, remove one element from it and compute the corresponding sum. If it doesn't meet the threshold, then discard it. Otherwise, report it as one of the sought combinations. For each `any` that can be changed, for each value in that column, enqueue a combination consisting of the current one with `any` replaced by that value, with the index locking down all previous `any` values.

Considering an output-sensitive bound, this is within a polynomial factor of optimal (in general, there can be exponentially many combinations).

In Python 3:

```
def overthreshold(data, threshold):
    queue = [(('any',) * len(data[0][0]), 0)]
    for combination, begin in queue:
        if sum(row[1] for row in data
               if all(x in {'any', y}
                      for x, y in zip(combination, row[0]))) < threshold:
            continue
        yield combination
        for i in range(begin, len(combination)):
            if combination[i] == 'any':
                queue.extend((combination[:i] + (x,) + combination[i+1:], i + 1)
                             for x in {row[0][i] for row in data})


def demo():
    data = [
        (('dog',    'house1', 'green'), 30),
        (('dog',    'house1', 'blue'),  15),
        (('cat',    'house1', 'green'), 20),
        (('cat',    'house2', 'red'),    5),
        (('turtle', 'house3', 'green'), 50),
    ]
    for combination in overthreshold(data, 50):
        print(combination)
```